# Backup files with rsync: error 23

Tags: permissions, backup, clipboard, rsync

I'm trying to make a backup of my /home to transfer all data from one computer to another. I wanted to save the backup on the same computer and than transfere it to another one. For safety reasons, I'm trying to learn how does it work on the computer without a lot of data (the new one) to be sure I won't delete something instead of copying it.

I've run in terminal:

```
sudo rsync -avz /home/maria /home/guest/backup
```

and I had as the result:

```
sent 58797801 bytes  received 23050 bytes  4705668.08 bytes/sec
total size is 100202958  speedup is 1.70
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1060) [sender=3.0.7]
```

I've tried once again, with the same result. I have no idea, which files were not transferred, what makes the whole backup useless for me (I wanted to do it automatically in order not to forget about something and loose it).

On both computers I have the same system (Ubuntu 10.04). Rsync version: 3.0.7-1ubuntu1.

Thanks for any tips

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Well, because you are running `rsync` in the verbose mode, you should be able to see in its output where the problem lies. Usually it is a *permission denied* error.

For example, suppose I want to back up the `~/.gvfs` folder:

```
$ sudo rsync -av /home/arrange/.gvfs /tmp
[sudo] password for arrange: 
sending incremental file list
rsync: link_stat "/home/arrange/.gvfs" failed: Permission denied (13)

sent 12 bytes  received 12 bytes  48.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1060) [sender=3.0.7]
```

So my advice is to list through the `rsync -av` output and look for similar errors.

Comment: I've run `sudo rsync -avz --exclude='/*/.gvfs' /home/maria /home/guest/backup` and this time no errors. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `'/*/.gvfs'` didn't work for me, ended up using `'.gvfs'`

Comment: If anyone runs it a list bigger than the terminal buffer you can just add `| grep failed` to your rsync command to list just the files that produced errors.

Comment: @devius +1 . Just a tip... I suggest to fetch the string "failed:" . The column at the end will allow to collect only rsync messages excluding files/dirs with "failed" in their name/path.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error as well.  In my case, rsync threw this error because I passed it a non-existent source directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you transfer files to remote storage (like freeNAS, etc) - don't forget to set correct rules.
Not only set **owner**, but include this ownerto **read-write list** also.

[image: freeNAS example]

I'm hooked on this.

Comment: O M G I've had weeks of trouble, thank you for taking the time to post this subtlety!

Answer (score 0):

In case you running in verbose mode and you want to see where is the "failed: Permission denied" message in all this output, run for a second time the command with grep:

```
rsync -avzP --exclude 'folderXX' /folder/ /backup-folder/ | grep failed
```

Now you can see only the files or folders that you cant backup